# What is the proper way to check string or list of strings length in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a React app and on a few pages I have to make requests to post data to the API and at least one of the strings I send have to be of a certain length. I have to write a function that takes either a single string or a list of strings and the required length and check the strings if their length is equal to the required length. If everything is ok, return true, else open a react-tostify notification and return false. Further development (like showing the first string that was of the incorrect length) might be done in the future. I've come up with a solution, but I think it could do with a little tweeking. I've also asked ChatGPT for advice. What do you think? How would you improve it?

Here's what I've come up with:

```
export const CheckCodeLength = (requiredLength: number, codeToCheck?: string, listOfCodes?: string[]) => {
    if (codeToCheck)
    {
        if (codeToCheck.length === requiredLength) return true;
        toast.error(Resources.Toasts.incorrectCodeLength());
        return false;
    }

    if (listOfCodes)
    {
        if (listOfCodes.filter(code => code.length === requiredLength).length === 0) return true;
        toast.error(Resources.Toasts.incorrectCodeLength());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's what Chat came up with (`console.log` is in place of `toast.error`):

```
function checkStringLength(length, input) {
  if (typeof input === 'string') {
    if (input.length !== length) {
      console.log('String length mismatch:', input);
    }
  } else if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i].length !== length) {
        console.log('String length mismatch at index', i, ':', input[i]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid input type');
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? If your code works, then this is the wrong place to ask the question.

Comment: `requiredLength: number, codeToCheck?: string, listOfCodes?: string[]` mean that `codeToCheck` is always the second argument and `listOfCodes` is always the third argument (if present of course). If you want to check if argument is an array you have to do this as chat gpt suggested.

Comment: I have an `if` inside another `if` twice. Besides that, I have 2 parameters for essentially the same thing. That's why I asked how would you improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the ChatGPT way and avoid passing multiple variable arguments unnecessarily.